# How to make test case fail if values are matching

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, assert

I have a scenario where I need to edit Employee name and when I click on Cancel button, Employee name field will wound back to its original value.Now I have to verify Cancel button is working or not.For that my approach is:

- 1.Get the value from the field using get attribute
- 2.Clear the field and enter new employee name
- 3.Click on cancel
- 4.Compare get attribute value and new employee name

My question is how do I fail the test case if both attribute value and new employee name are same.I used both If condition and Assert condition.Both are not working.Any solutions to this

```
 Assert.assertTrue(getLastNameValue.equals(LastName));.//It will fail if both the values mismatch.but i want to make it fail only if both the values are equal
```

And one more method I tried

```
if(!getLastNameValue.equalsIgnoreCase(LastName)) {
        log.info("Edits are wounded back after clicking on Cancel button");
    }
```

Comment: `assertNotEquals`?

Comment: You can negate the condition or use `Assert.assertFalse(condition)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options...

1. Following your current testing style  `Assert.assertFalse(getLastNameValue.equals(LastName));`
2. Using Hamcrest `assertThat(getLastNameValue, not(LastName));` is more readable and creates a better error message than your variant. Also offers a lot of matchers.
3. Even better readability but all the same in terms of functionality `assertThat(getLastNameValue, is(not(equalTo(LastName))));`

Comment: You'd be better off using 2 or 3 because if you use 1 and it fails, you will get the message expected false but got true... which is not useful at all for debugging. If you use 2 or 3 you will get expected "String 1" but got "String 2" so you will start with what the wrong value was so that will give you a better idea of what might have gone wrong in the test to get into the bad state, etc.